# xml Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7xSr.png)

I just make a new project and it doesn't work.
Look at the link. Some of files like 'colors.xml', there is a problem that the files are made that way.
What can I do?

Comment: Instead of `<application>` use `<resources>` and add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the head. And use `color` instead of `component`. Example `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> </resources>`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents/53476487#53476487

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `colors.xml` with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ff7c30</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fe5d00</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#009688</color>
</resources>
```

When you want to add a color just add :

```
<color name="yourColor">#YOURCOLOR</color>
```

And you can use it like this for example :

```
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

Comment: Ok. but you know that Originally, It should be in the right format from the start of making the new project. But there is the same problem after deleting and reinstalling the android studio. I don't want to replace my color.xml every time I make a project...

Comment: Yes, it should be in the right format. Did you tried to update Android Studio ? Also, try to update your android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You must synchronize your project first once you created a new project to add those dependencies that validate the codes including the Layout Files. The synchronize button is at the right top of the Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. We can't use capitals in image files.